# JBoss Eclipse - Deploying a War with Jar

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I am using JBoss AS 7 with Eclipse Indigo, and i have a problem with deploying a WAR.

In fact, i have 2 projects :

- First containing the "***Logic part***": The differents EJB (Session Bean + Entity Bean)
- Second containing the "***Web part***": Related to the web application, which have some JSF, xhtml and backing bean stuff.

So basically, I added to my Second project classpath, the first (build path -> project -> add).

Then i try to make a basic xhtml file (form), interacting with a backing bean, interacting itself with the Session Bean of my first project.

But when i try to deploy my application, i have the following exception :

```
catching: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error loading class MY_BACKINGBEAN_CLASS
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MY_SESSIONBEAN_CLASS
```

I don't get why this error happens, because i included in my classpath the project containing all the session bean.

I know there are a lot of thing about deploying war, but i didn't find any good solution.

Thanks.